# Expanding variables in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

The script below works in bash but not in zsh. I think it is because in the variable `OPTS`, I am "expanding" (not sure if this is the right word) the variable `$EXCLUDE`, and this syntax doesn't work in zsh. How would I replace that line to make it work on zsh?

```
SRC="/path_to_source"
DST="/path_to_dest"
EXCLUDE=".hg"  
OPTS="-avr --delete --progress --exclude=${EXCLUDE} --delete-excluded"                                               

rsync $OPTS $SRC $DST
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem here is that `$OPTS` is not split into several arguments on the `rsync` command line. In `zsh` syntax, use:

```
rsync ${=OPTS} $SRC $DST
```

(an alternative is to simulate standard shell behavior globably with the option `-o shwordsplit`…)

From the manpage:

> One  commonly encountered difference [in `zsh`] is that variables substituted
>   onto the command line are not split into words.  See the description
>   of  the shell option `SH_WORD_SPLIT` in the section 'Parameter Expansion'
>   in `zshexpn(1)`.  In `zsh`, you can either explicitly request the
>   splitting (e.g. `${=foo}`)  or  use  an  array when you want a variable to
>   expand to more than one word.  See the section 'Array Parameters' in
>   `zshparam(1)`.

Comment: Is there anyway I can make it portable to bash?
I want to use the same script/function to be usable in both bash and zsh.

Comment: @balki: You can start your script with `set -o shwordsplit 2>/dev/null` to tell `zsh` to use `sh` word splitting. Or you can use arrays, as described by [Gilles](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19530#19569).

Comment: Thanks a lot, and thanks for the quote from the man page

Comment: Note that the solution of making OPTS an array (explained in Gilles's answer) is better than forcing word splitting, because it allows the options to contain word delimiters. If you force word splitting, an option like `--include-from="filename with space"` will be split into several words.

Comment: I finally figured out a good mnemonic for `${=foo}` syntax: the two bars in `=` are like two pieces of a longer or thicker line that was just split apart.

Answer (score 13):

The problem doesn't come from `$EXCLUDE`, it comes from `$OPTS`. Your script relies on word splitting happening to `$OPTS`. This is a bad idea; for example it will fail if you ever change `$EXCLUDE` to contain a pattern and `--exclude=$EXCLUDE` comes to match a file in the current directory, or if you ever change `$EXCLUDE` to contain whitespace.

`$OPTS` is a list of words, not a word. If you only need your script to work in ksh, bash and zsh, make it an array:

```
SRC="/path_to_source"
DST="/path_to_dest"
EXCLUDE=".hg"
OPTS=(-avr --delete --progress --exclude="$EXCLUDE" --delete-excluded)
rsync "${OPTS[@]}" "$SRC" "$DST"
```

If you only intend the script to work in zsh, you can simplify the last line:

```
rsync $OPTS $SRC $DST
```

If you want the script to work in every shell, you need to use the positional parameters. They are the only array available.

```
set -- -avr --delete --progress --exclude="$EXCLUDE" --delete-excluded
rsync "$@" "$SRC" "$DST"
```

If you have a shell script that you want to be able to run conveniently with zsh, put this line at the beginning — it tells zsh to act like ksh, and it's a no-op on other shells.

```
emulate ksh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: +1 for the pure zsh solution, as I came here looking to improve my oh-my-zsh profile.

Comment: Nice trick of using the POSIX shell's positional parameters via `set --`.

Answer (score 6):

To complete Stéphane Gimenez answer (I cannot comment yet), one solution is to make your script portable to bash by checking if you are using `zsh` and then transform `$OPTS` into an array like this

```
[ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] && set -A OPTS ${=OPTS}
```

Then your rsync command will work.

Comment: What is the meaning of `:-` after `ZSH_VERSION`?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Looks like the "Use default value" form of parameter expansion. In `${parameter:-word}` if `parameter` is unset or null then then expansion of `word` is substituted. Otherwise the expansion of `parameter` is used. `word` can be omitted and that leaves an empty string in the above example. Evaluating `-n` against an empty (zero length) string results in false. So `set` won't be executed if you're not using zsh.