# Zsh string variable containing multi words must be assigned to an array

Tags: zsh, array, assignment

How to have Zsh string variable containing multi words separated by space be assigned to an array so that each word is the array element

```
s='run help behind me'
a=($s)
m=${a[0]}
n=${a[1]}
print "m=$m"
echo n=$n

m=
n=run help behind me
```

confusing, so simple but still cannot do it so..
Really please help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to many shells, zsh does not perform word splitting during variable expansion by default. As explained in `man zshexpn`, you can use the `=` modifier to enable splitting:

> ```
>    ${=spec}
>           Perform  word splitting using the rules for SH_WORD_SPLIT during
>           the evaluation of spec, but regardless of whether the  parameter
>           appears  in  double  quotes; if the `=' is doubled, turn it off.
>           This forces parameter expansions to be split into separate words
>           before  substitution, using IFS as a delimiter.  This is done by
>           default in most other shells.
> ```

i.e. `a=( ${=s} )` or `a=( $=s )`. As well, remember that zsh arrays are indexed from 1 not 0.

Those, like the `a=( $s )` of `bash`¹ split according to complex rules involving the `$IFS` special characters. You can also split based on an arbitrary given string by using the `s` *parameter expansion flag*:

```
a=( ${(s[ ])s} ) # split $s on spaces only, discarding empty elements
a=( "${(@s[ ])s}" ) # split $s on spaces, preserving empty elements
```

See also [Expanding variables in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19530/expanding-variables-in-zsh).

---

<sup>¹ though note that contrary to `bash`, it doesn't do globbing on top of that for which you'd also need the `~` operator: `a=( $=~s )`.</sup>