# problematic script: query buku, select via fzf and then print using (again) buku

Tags: zsh, fzf

First and foremost, thank you for taking the time to review the question.

I have the following script: select an array of IDs from `buku`'s database, and then use `buku` again to print information using the previously selected ids.

```
selected_ids=$(buku --print --format 3 | fzf | cut --fields=1) 
&& test="$(buku --print $selected_ids --format 10)"
```

Problem: the value of `test` (`echo $test`) is blank when I select *multiple entries* via `fzf`.

I tried multiple solutions, including piping into `tr`:

```
selected_ids=$(buku --print --format 3 | fzf | cut --fields=1 | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs) 
&& test="$(buku --print $selected_ids --format 10)
```

but to no avail.

My intuition suggests the problem is maybe `$selected_ids` being interpreted as a whole string. Why? Because when I select via `fzf` only *one entry*, the value of `$test` contains the selected value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a *string* of IDs, not an array - and zsh does not perform word splitting on variable expansions by default. See for example [Zsh string variable containing multi words must be assigned to an array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/745913/zsh-string-variable-containing-multi-words-must-be-assigned-to-an-array)

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot @steeldriver :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @steeldriver's suggestion, I found the answer.
Will post it here for posterity's sake.

```
selected_ids=$(buku --print --format 3 | fzf | cut --fields=1) 
&& test="$(buku --print ${=selected_ids} --format 10)"
```